# Codbmirror on highlight event?

Tags: codemirror

I would like to add a marker in Codemirror after syntax highlighting has completed, so that I can identify certain tokens and place them there. Is there some sort of syntax highlighting completed event, and also, a way to check the tokens after that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on the DOM structure to recognize tokens, but use methods like [`getLineTokens`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getLineTokens) or [`getTokenAt`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getTokenAt) to inspect tokens. That way, you don't need to wait for a highlight to happen.